# WooCommerce 2.0+ discount price per quantity and variation on product page

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, discount, product-variations

Using Mystile theme in the latest version of Woocommerce, I overrode variation.php in order to show discount price depending on quantity and variation chosen. I have 3 attributes : "marquage", "couleurs" and "couleurs à marquer".

Here's my PHP, added just after `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`.

I hope your eyes won't bleed, I've been working on websites for less than one year (I was a printer before \o/ did not know anything about coding).

```
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$variation_id=$available_variations[0]['variation_id']; 
$variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price1 = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
$sales_price1 = $variable_product1 ->sale_price;
$variation_id=$available_variations[1]['variation_id']; 
$variable_product2= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price2 = $variable_product2 ->regular_price;
$sales_price2 = $variable_product2 ->sale_price;
$variation_id=$available_variations[2]['variation_id']; 
$variable_product3= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price3 = $variable_product3 ->regular_price;
$sales_price3 = $variable_product3 ->sale_price;
$variation_id=$available_variations[3]['variation_id']; 
$variable_product4= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price4 = $variable_product4 ->regular_price;
$sales_price4 = $variable_product4 ->sale_price;
$variation_id=$available_variations[4]['variation_id']; 
$variable_product5= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price5 = $variable_product5 ->regular_price;
$sales_price5 = $variable_product5 ->sale_price;
$variation_id=$available_variations[5]['variation_id']; 
$variable_product6= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price6 = $variable_product6 ->regular_price;
$sales_price6 = $variable_product6 ->sale_price;
$variations_prices = array($available_variations[0][attributes][attribute_pa_couleurs] => $regular_price1, $available_variations[1][attributes][attribute_pa_couleurs] => $regular_price2, $available_variations[2][attributes][attribute_pa_couleurs] => $regular_price3, $available_variations[3][attributes][attribute_pa_couleurs] => $regular_price4, $available_variations[4][attributes][attribute_pa_couleurs] => $regular_price5, $available_variations[5][attributes][attribute_pa_couleurs] => $regular_price6);
```

Right, this works fine.
These lines allow me to capture variations in prices in variables, only for Couleurs attribute at this moment.
I could add it to `functions.php`, but I want to get my `json_encode($variations_prices);` in jQuery. So that's what I did in this script, just after my custom PHP, still in `variation.php`.

Words SOME_BAD_PHP means opening or ending php, is_less_than means < (sorry for that, you're actually reading my first post in Stackoverflow :-) )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     function calculate_price(){
     var my_array = SOME_BAD_PHP echo json_encode($variations_prices); END_SOME_BAD_PHP;
     var qty_prod = $('.qty').val();
     var coul = $('#pa_couleurs').val();
     var marquage = $('#pa_marquage').val(); 
     var couleurs_marquage = $('#pa_couleurs-a-marquer').val();
     if(jQuery.inArray($('select#pa_couleurs option:selected').val(), my_array)!== -1){ 
     }else {
     var price_in_array = my_array[$('select#pa_couleurs option:selected').val()];
     var price_coul_min = price_in_array;}
            if(qty_prod is_less_than 50) { 
                var total_to_pay = price_coul_min * qty_prod;}
            else if(qty_prod >= 50) { 
                var price_redux = price_coul_min - 5 / 100;
                var total_to_pay = price_redux * qty_prod;}
     if (total_to_pay > 0){
     $('#price_me').html('Le prix est de ' + total_to_pay + ' euros pour la sélection'); 
     }else{}
   };
```

And finally I added a simple `<span id="price_me"></span>` in my product page.

These lines of code show discount prices depending on variation and quantity chosen in a span that has "price_me" id. Works fine; unfortunately, that's not nice and it probably contains errors.

I hope my code (that works locally) will help others. I just want to do it properly :-D But there's no loop and some bad PHP in jQuery...

**Is there a way to have a PHP function that returns my `json_encode($array)` to another function, that adds my jQuery script to WooCommerce (using `wp_enqueue_script` for example)?**

Comment: Problem solved by adding js script to theme. Overriding cart with php function can be seen at http://cyrilchalamon.fr/woocommerce-loverride-du-panier/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included JS script that overrides Ajax prices, then i created a custom function that overrides woocommerce cart. Woocommerce cart override code can be seen at my own website, js file depends on what u're selling.
Both work a charm, thanks to friends.

Comment: I've definitely added it to my MustToDoListIn WC. Actually my problem is solved, but i've added Ajax script to Woocommerce that is definitely useful.